# Cannot set a character count limit on Textfield Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I'm developing an Android app using Jetpack Compose.
I'd like to set a character count limit on Textfield, but if I try this code, users can input maximum 1201 characters(maxChar+1), and if users input 1201 characters(exceed maxChar), they cannot delete any letters.

```
@Composable
fun PostEdit(navController: NavController, content: String, id: String) {
    var editedContent = remember { mutableStateOf("$content")}
    val maxChar = 1200
    ...

         OutlinedTextField(
                value = editedContent.value,         
                onValueChange = { newValue: String ->
                    if (editedContent.value.length <= maxChar) {
                        editedContent.value = newValue
                    }
                },
                label = { Text("Content", fontSize = 20.sp, color = Brown) },
                ...
```

On a different view, I set a character count limit, too, and it is successful. The difference is, this time, there is no parameter in "var intro". This is the code.

```
@Composable
fun Signup(navController: NavController) 
    var intro by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val maxChar = 100
    ...
         OutlinedTextField(
                value = intro,
                onValueChange = {
                    if (it.length <= maxChar) {
                        intro = it
                    }
                },
                label = { Text("Introduction", fontSize = 20.sp, color = Brown) },
                ...
```

Could someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one (`intro`) you are using the implicit `it` parameter not the `intro` state variable

```
 onValueChange = { // <-- implicit `it`
         if (it.length <= maxChar) {
              intro = it 
          }
 }
```

while on the first (`editedContent`) one you are using the state variable instead so when editedContent's `length` reaches `1200` and you typed another character it will still satisfy your onValueChange condition `<=`, making it `1201`, and when you attempt to `delete`, the condition won't be satisfied anymore, no changes will happen  to `editedContent`

```
onValueChange = { newValue: String -> // <--  use this
     if (editedContent.value.length <= maxChar) {
          editedContent.value = newValue 
     }
}
```

so do what you did on the second one to your first one and it will work

```
 onValueChange = { newValue: String ->
     if (newValue.length <= maxChar) {
          editedContent.value = newValue
     }
 }
```

Comment: It works! And I learned a lot. Thanks.